Execute a Gatling scenario exactly once
I want to execute a Gatling scenario exactly once (i.e. execute a single virtual user with a single iteration). I don't want to execute it for a duration, I don't want to concurrent users, I don't want to have users per sec.
final ScenarioBuilder scenario = scenario("exactly once")
  .exec(http.get("/something"))
  .exec(http.get("/somethingelse"));

setUp(scenario.injectClosed(
  constantConcurrentUsers(1).iterations(1) // what to put here?
);

Running this test, I expect exactly 2 requests hitting my web server: 1 request to /something and 1 request to /somethingelse.
The injection docs don't really mention anything about iterations.
Coming from k6, this would be as simple as k6 run -u1 -i1 test.js (actually the default, equivalent to k6 run test.js) or with shared-iterations executor (again, defaults to 1 user with 1 iteration).

Pretty simple - atOnceUsers(1)
atOnceUsers(nbUsers): Injects a given number of users at once.

Thanks! So obvious that I missed it. (In my defense: the docs are a bit confusing at times and the single example mixes 5 different injectors)

@knittl Please feel free to contribute to the documentation if you find things lacking or confusion, it would be much appreciated (see Edit link at the bottom of each page). Now, you also have to give up on k6's mental model. In Gatling, we have virtual users started based on an injection profile, and if you want to make them loop, you need to include this loop in your scenario. Gatling is closer to what real world users do.

@StéphaneLANDELLE what exactly do you mean with "k6's mental model"? k6 starts virtual users who will execute a defined test function. Users from different scenarios can execute different test functions. Scenarios can define different "executors" (I think this is what Gatling calls "injectors") to model open and closed work loads.

k6 is very close to tools like ab or wrk: define a number of concurrent executors that will execute a script and a number of iterations so each executor iterate on the script. The mental model there is to "recycle" virtual users. These tools are originally intended for closed workload models. In Gatling, you're not supposed to recycle virtual users. Create new ones instead. And if you want loops (probably not on the full scenario, eg not on the login steps), make it part of the scenario.

Regarding terms in Gatling: what you call executors we call "virtual users". And "injector" is the term we used to use for "load generator" (that we now use), ie a Gatling engine instance. It's mostly used in Gatling Enterprise that supports distributed load tests.

@StéphaneLANDELLE no, executors and virtual users are distinct things (in k6). k6 supports both closed (shared iterations, constant VUs executorse) and open (arrival rate executors) work loads. New VUs are allocated as needed to reach the target rate.
